Meta-analysis vs mixed-effect model to estimate effect size
I have data from three previous experiments and I want to use them in a power analysis to calculate the required sample size for a new study. A classical way to do this, is to make a meta analysis to get an estimate for (in this case) the standardized means difference, which can then be fed into the sample size calculation. I have done this using the function rma (performing a randon effect meta analysis) of the R-package metafor. I have done this for a demo data set (code below) and as a result I get an estimate for the treatment effect (means difference) of 6.86 with se 2.238.

library(lme4)
library(metafor)

# The demo dataset:
# treatment: categorical variable: 0: treatment group, 1: control group
# study: categorical variable indicating study number from 1 to 3
# y: simulated measurement value
y <- c(15.1,14.9,12.1,17.3,14.1,16.2,15.0,16.0,25.2,23.5,27.1,20.9,29.4,25.3,24.8,25.1,
       8.2,11.3,10.0,10.1,9.9,12.0,8.0,10.9,18.0,17.0,19.3,22.2,16.1,17.1,17.8,17.2,
       22.0,23.1,20.9,22.1,21.8,19.9,24.6,21.9,24.5,26.4,22.1,24.1,24.0,23.7,26.5,25.8)
treatment <- as.factor(rep(c(rep(0,8),rep(1,8)),3))
study <- as.factor(c(rep(1,16),rep(2,16),rep(3,16)))

# random effect meta analysis using the package metafor
rma(measure="MD",
    n1i=c(8,8,8),
    n2i=c(8,8,8),
    m1i=c(mean(y[9:16]),mean(y[25:32]),mean(y[41:48])),
    m2i=c(mean(y[1:8]),mean(y[17:24]),mean(y[33:40])),
    sd1i=c(sd(y[9:16]),sd(y[25:32]),sd(y[41:48])),        
    sd2i=c(sd(y[1:8]),sd(y[17:24]),sd(y[33:40]))
    )

However, as I do not only have the summary data for each of the three data in the meta-analysis but actually all the raw data I could, instead of the rma, also estimate the treatment effect directly with a mixed effect regression model.
mod <- lmer(y ~ treatment + (1|study) + (1|study:treatment))
summary(mod)

Doing so, I get a slightly different estimate for the treatment effect, 6.904 , with an se of 2.231. The difference is not big, but it is there. I am not surprised, that I get slightly different results, because I am starting off with different information: “only” the summary statistics (mean, sd) in one case, and the full raw data in the other case. My question is, which one is the “better” way to estimate the effect for the effect size calculation? Most power calculations that I see are based on meta-analyses (because usually the raw data are not easily available as data are extracted from the literature where authors often only report the summary statistics). However, with my naïve intuition I would argue that, if I do have the raw data, then the mixed model which takes as input all the raw data should be more precise because it makes use of more information. Is there any reason why I should therefore not base my effect size estimate on the mixed model outcomes, but use a rma as most others do?

See this answer. In short, when the full data is available, there is no advantage to using precalculated effect sizes

As an aside, using (1|study:treatment) adds a random effect for treatment, which I don't think is what you want. The difference in standard error is much larger if you omit this term.

The difference between the two approaches comes down to certain modeling choices. For example, the meta-analytic model used above implicitly uses fixed study effects, not random study effects as used in the mixed-effects model. Also, the mixed-effects model assumes a single residual error variance component, while the meta-analytic model allows the residual variance to differ across studies. As long as one uses equivalent models, the results from the meta-analytic approach and the model using the raw data (what is also called an 'individual participant data meta-analysis' or IPDMA) will be identical. Some further discussion about this can be found in this article:
Burke, D. L., Ensor, J., & Riley, R. D. (2017). Meta-analysis using individual participant data: One-stage and two-stage approaches, and why they may differ. Statistics in Medicine, 36(5), 855-875. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.7141
To demonstrate, let's refit the random-effects model, but using a t-test for the coefficient and setting the degrees of freedom to $n-p$ where $n$ is the total sample size and $p$ the number of studies:
rma(measure="MD",
    n1i=c(8,8,8),
    n2i=c(8,8,8),
    m1i=c(mean(y[9:16]),mean(y[25:32]),mean(y[41:48])),
    m2i=c(mean(y[1:8]),mean(y[17:24]),mean(y[33:40])),
    sd1i=c(sd(y[9:16]),sd(y[25:32]),sd(y[41:48])),
    sd2i=c(sd(y[1:8]),sd(y[17:24]),sd(y[33:40])),
    test="t", dfs=length(y)-nlevels(study))

Now let's fit a mixed-effects model with fixed study effects, a random treatment effect, and allowing the residual variance to differ across studies. We can do this using the nlme package:
library(nlme)
treat1 <- ifelse(treatment == 1, 1, 0)
mod <- lme(y ~ 0 + treat1 + factor(study), 
           random = ~ 0 + treat1 | study, 
           weights=varIdent(form = ~ 1 | study))
summary(mod)

The results (leaving aside minor numerical differences due to differences in the underlying model fitting algorithms) are the same.
So as long as one makes identical modeling choices, the results from an IPDMA will be identical to those from a 'two-stage' analysis and hence there is no inherent advantage to using the raw data (unless one starts to bring in predictors at the person level).
